# BIG O complexity n or n^2log(n)

Tags: big-o

which is bigger in complexity n or n^2log(n)
i know that log(n) is lower than n. but how about the upper case and what will be the big O OF THIS EQUATION

Comment: Which do *you* think is bigger?  If you explain your reasoning and are wrong, someone could point out *why*.

Answer (score 0):

Well, n = n^1, and 1 < 2log(n), so that should be enough to tell you which of n^1 and n^2log(n) is bigger.